# How to get selected value from dropdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, drop-down-menu, switch-statement

Now, before you tell me that this is an over-asked question, I already tried looking at multiple versions of this question, and when I tried their solutions, none of them work for me. So I'm going to try to get direct help.

Anyways, I have a dropdown list that contains U.S states that each correspond to an energy cost. I am trying to make it so that when the user selects a state, the Javascript code detects the change, finds the value of the selected option, and sets a variable (declared in a switch statement) based upon that selection.

However, the problem is, no matter what I do, it does not work. I don't know if I'm misspelling something, or I need to write a certain thing that I don't know about, but no matter what I'm doing wrong, it does not work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="question">
      <p><b>In which U.S. state are you currently living in?</b></p>
      <select id="stateselect">
        <option value="choose" selected="selected">[none]</option>
        <option value="al">Alabama</option>
        <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
        <option value="az">Arizona</option>
        <option value="ar">Arkansas</option>
        /* Removed most of the options for sake of space*/
      </select>
    </div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var energyCost;
var state = document.GetElementById('stateselect');
function getEnergyCost() {
  switch (state.value) {
    case 'choose':
      energyCost = 0.00;
      break;
    case 'al':
      energyCost = 0.13;
      break;
    case 'ak':
      energyCost = 0.21;
      break;
    case 'az':
      energyCost = 0.12;
      break;
    case 'ar':
      energyCost = 0.10;
      break;
   /* Ditto */
  }
}
state.addEventListener('change', getEnergyCost, false);
```

Would someone mind giving me some assistance with this? Thanks!

Note: I need the answers in plain Javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo. It's `getElementById`, not `GetElementById`.

Comment: How could I have not seen that?! Oh well, thank you and @JackRogers for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Change

```
var state = document.GetElementById('stateselect');
```

To

```
var state = document.getElementById('stateselect');
```

The capital on `get` in `getElementById` makes it an invalid function.